# Select input ordering

Tags: jquery, html

So I have 3 select input fields and I was wondering if its possible to disable the other options once they have been selected. ie:

```
<tr id="row1">
    <th>Row 1</th>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected>2 selected so 1+3 are disabled</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="row2">
    <th>Row 2</th>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value="1" selected>1 selected 2+3 are disabled</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="row3">
    <th>Row 3</th>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3" selected>3 (you get it...)</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If you disable the other options after selecting one, how is the user supposed to change their selection?

Comment: @MattBall I'm guessing by unchecking the box, but that is a weird UX.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for are radio buttons, not option selects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).find('option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true)
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3UQtj/)

Comment: gold star! <3 Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 2):

You can bind an onchange event to the select. Then select which option elements were not selected and disable this. If you are already familiar with jQuery, you may do it this way:

```
$("select").bind("change", function(){
        $(this).children("option:not(:selected)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the other options will prevent the user from changing their selection anyway, so just use javascript to remove all other options.

The quick, dirty way would be

```
<select onchange='for(vari=0, l=this.options.length; i<l; i++){ if(this.options[i].selected) continue; this.remove(i); }'>
```

No Jquery needed. However, I would not reccomend mixing javascript with html unless you don't have any other external javascript that could inmport and apply this as a handler for these particular select statements.